# DmlException Creating CMS Library/Folders

Tags: apex, dml, content, dmlexception, mixed-dml

I have some Apex code written to create a new **Account**, and then create a new **Library** (*ContentWorkspace*) and new **Folder** (*ContentFolder*) within that Library to house assets for that Account. It appears that one of these Content objects is a "non-setup" object, so the following error is being thrown: `MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): ContentFolder, original object: ContentWorkspace: []`

Here is the code I have written to accomplish this:

```
// create Account
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = 'Test';
insert acc;

// create Library
ContentWorkspace workspace = new ContentWorkspace();
workspace.Name = 'Test';
insert workspace;

// create Folder within that Library
workspace = [select Id from ContentWorkspace where Name =: 'Test'];
ContentFolder parentFolder = [select Id from ContentFolder where Name =: workspace.Id];
ContentFolder folder = new ContentFolder();
folder.Name = 'Test';
folder.ParentContentFolderId = parentFolder.Id;
insert folder;
```

Am I missing something? Or is this just not possible to sequentially do like this in Apex? The only "workaround" for this DmlException I found online was to make the DML operation for the "non-setup" object in a `@future` method. This won't work because I need the **Library** to exist in order to properly parent the **Folders**, so if the **Library** creation is in a `@future` method, the **Folder** creation code won't work since the **Library** doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Isn't it just the fact that you create an `Account` first? Why not just create that asynchronously?

Comment: No, this error still occurs even if you remove the `Account` creation piece. It appears that `ContentWorkspace` is a "setup" object but `ContentFolder` is not.

Comment: Clarification, is this in an Apex unit test or actual production code?

Comment: Actual code, not a test class.

Answer (score 0):

One route to do this is to bounce through a Queueable chain to maintain your state while you separate the manipulation of setup and non-setup objects into separate transactions. Here's a sketch of what that could look like:

```
public class ContentQueueable implements Queueable {
    private Account a;
    private ContentWorkspace cw;
    private ContentFolder cf;

    public ContentQueueable() {
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
        if (this.a == null) {
            this.a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
            insert this.a;
            System.enqueueJob(this); // chain to continue
        } else if (this.cw == null) {
            this.cw = new ContentWorkspace(Name = 'Test');
            insert this.cw;
            System.enqueueJob(this); // chain to continue
        } else if (this.cf == null) {
           // create Folder within that Library
            ContentFolder parentFolder = [select Id from ContentFolder where Name = :this.cw.Id];
            this.cf = new ContentFolder();
            this.cf.Name = 'Test';
            this.cf.ParentContentFolderId = parentFolder.Id;
            insert this.cf;
        }
    }
}
```

(This throws a different Content-related error which I'm not familiar with related to permissions on the created ContentWorkspace, but it does avoid the Mixed DML problem).